# Closing multiprocessing logger handler

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, multiprocessing

I have followed the following gist https://mattgathu.github.io/multiprocessing-logging-in-python/ to create multiprocessing logger in Python.

The problem -The main process may quit even though the queue is not empty, I want it to wait until the logger writes them.

How can I modify the above specified code to support this?

Thank you.

Comment: Python has a QueueHandler since 3.2. No need to use a custom implementation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler

Comment: @blues thank you, I'm using python 2.7